# Virtual GPIO emulation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, emulation, gpio

Does exist a virtual GPIO driver to be used for a programming needs?

I have to develop a software on my Linux PC, and then try it on some embedded systems with physical GPIOs (C.H.I.P., OpenWRT, and so on...)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution exists and is available since kernel 4.10 as GPIO mockup  driver.

Some references for you:

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.10/tools/testing/selftests/gpio/gpio-mockup.sh
- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpio/gpio-mockup.c

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://github.com/maquefel/virtual_gpio_basic also.

In such case gpios are indistinguishable from real hardware.

Also latest qemu versions have gpio support with interrupts.