# Is there a Raspberry Pi hardware emulator that supports custom ISOs?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, emulation, development-environment, iso

I have a custom OS built for running on various RPi hardwares (RPi 3, RPi 4, RPi CM3), but developing on real hardware is tedious, expensive and limiting.

Are there any Raspberry Pi hardware emulators out there that will allow me to load my custom ISO? Ideally it would mimic all the hardware outputs and inputs such as IO with PWM, Wifi, graphics. Obviously testing will still be carried out on actual hardware.

I've had a look on my favourite search engine but all the results I've found seem to be focused on retro-games development, or limited to a single OS (i.e. Raspbian).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of the complex hardware (i.e. CPU, GPU, RAM, network cards, disks and so on), [qemu has you covered](https://www.qemu.org/), there also seem to be a `--machine raspi3b` flag that's supposed to be close to a Raspberry Pi 3B but I can't find any information about what is included exactly.

If you want to emulate some other raspi, you can use `qemu-system-aarch64 --machine help` to list all 64bits ARM devices that can be emulated by qemu (note that as of writing this, qemu has no support for the raspi4).

If the emulation offered by qemu doesn't include some hardware you want, a lot of things can be emulated using dummy kernel modules such as the GPIO mockup driver [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44626161/7337816) and the [mac80211_hwsim module](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/mac80211_hwsim/mac80211_hwsim.html). It's probably not as close to the hardware as you'd like though, if you prefer a more hands on approach you could create qemu "hardware" to be a perfect replica of the pi.